# How to add files with a specific extension in a directory recursively

Tags: git

Assuming there are the following files:

- `git/dir/a.java`
- `git/dir/b.java`
- `git/dir/c.java`
- `git/dir/a.swp`
- `git/dir/b.swp`
- `git/dir/subdir/d.java`
- `git/dir/subdir/e.java`

I intend to add only all the Java files to the *staged* phase, `git add git/dir/*.java` does not work recursively, meaning the files in `git add git/dir/subdir` will not be successfully added. Whereas the `git add git/dir/*` will add all the files inside `git/dir` recursively including those with extension `.swp`, which are not planned to be added to the *staged* phase.

**Question: is it possible to add all files with a specific extension inside a directory recursively with one command? If possible how?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a combination of shell script and git
`find git/dir/ -type f -name "*.java" | xargs git add`

Answer (score 2):

```
shopt globstar
```

If `globstar` is `off`, then run `shopt -s globstar` to turn it on. And then,

```
git add git/dir/**/*.java
```

`**` matches 0 or more levels of directories. But it also adds `git/dir/subdir/subsubdir/o.java` if it exists.

As @sschuberth comment says, you can use `git add "git/dir/**/*.java"`.

It works on Ubuntu and git-bash-for-windows. Not sure if it also works on other OS.

Comment: You don't actually need to enabled `globstar` as Git itself also perform wildcard expansion, i.e. a quoted `git add "dir/**/*.java"` works, too.

Comment: @sschuberth Thank you! I didn't know it.